# Form action value not getting from attr() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, broadleaf-commerce

I have one form in html

**html file**

```
<blc:form value method=POST action="@{/cart/add}">
  ..... 
  .....
    <div>
      <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="addToCart"/> <!-- submit button -->
    </div>
     <div id="productInCart"></div>
  ......
    </div>
</blc:form>
```

when I click the button I need to send `ajax` request to the server by taking request from `form action attribute`

**JavaScript**

```
$document.on('click','#addToCart',function(e){
alert('test1')
var url = button.parents('form').attr('action')
alert("request url:-"+url)//control is not reaching up to here
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        success: function(){
             $("#productInCart").html("")
             alert('success')
          }
        error: function(){
             alert('fail')
          }
    });
});
```

Control is entering into function and printing the `alert` value `test1` but unable to reach after `url` variable, above code is failing to submit the request to the server through `ajax` call because it is failing to get the value of `action` attribute from the form.
Can anyone help me what is wrong in above code.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy in between `<div>`  `<input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="addToCart"/>`

Comment: How did you get the `button` ? Can you show that?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy sorry I didn't get you what your asking, what do you mean `how did you get the button?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("[name=form]").attr("action",'url');
       or
$(this).parents("form").attr('action')
```

Comment: thank you for your reply i am getting the value saying `urlundefined`

Comment: than you have to define url like this
  $("[name=form]").attr('action', 'url');

Comment: yeah your second approach is getting url value thank you, but `ajax` request is failing and entering into `error` function.. +1

Comment: than console.log('url')
are you getting url?

Comment: yeah bro url is getting.. thank you but I am looking for `ajax` call it is failing.

Comment: you have to pass callback function in success

Comment: my question is about getting `action` value from the form, you solved it thank you, now i'll look for ajax thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110742/discussion-between-subbu-royal-and-spartan).